# Swap keys and values in dictionary with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Lets say we have a dictionary with unique values:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

and we would like to swap keys and values like:

```
{ 1: 'a', 2: 'b' }
```

how to do it with underscore?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In `underscore.js` there is method  [`_.invert`](http://underscorejs.org/#invert)

```js
console.log(_.invert({ a: 1, b: 2 }))
```

```html
<script src="//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: lodash also has _.invert